# Why jCarousel Next/Prev button is not enabling after adding item into it

Tags: jcarousel

Initially I've three li items under a ul. A jCarousel instance is created with the ui and it shows the carousel successfully with the three li items. By default the carousel shows three items and hence the Next/Prev button is disabled.

Now I add a new li item under the carousel using $('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel').add(...) method. It shows that the li is added under the ul with proper jcarouselidex, but the carousel's Next/Prev button remains disabled and hence I can't see it in the carousel.

NOTE: If I create carousel with 4 or more li items then the Next/Prev buttons become enable and it work perfectly.

What I've tried: I see the Next/Prev buttons' div is in disable, so after adding new item, I enable the divs. The Next/Prev buttons are now enable but doesn't do anything.

Any work around will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This took some figuring out on my part as well. After calling the reload() function, I called the size() function with the new size of the array. Here's a sample:

```
            carousel = jQuery('#header_selector').data('jcarousel');
            carousel.reset();
            for(n = 0; n < response.images.length; n++) {
                carousel.add(n, '<img src="' + response.images[n] + '" />' );
            }
            carousel.scroll(carousel.first);
            carousel.reload();
            carousel.size(response.images.length);
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Yes I did also the same thing of carousel.reset() carousel.size() with the existing carousel object and it worked for me as well. Sorry that I couldn't add it to this post in time. Thanks for your reply.